# Updating cell value from callback in ag grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I need to update  the value of one of the cells in a row in ag-grid as soon as the onCellEditingStopped callback is called (this happens when a user exits any other cell on that row).

I have this code which is based on the single cell update example at [Ag grid single cell update](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/data-update-single-row-cell/)

```
onCellEditingStopped: {function(event) {
 event.node.setDataValue("cell_to_update","a new value");
}
}
```

which should update the cell with field "cell_to_update" but it doesnt.

I am wondering if that is because I am calling it from this specific callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is by forcing the refresh, like

```
onCellEditingStopped: {function(event) {
 event.node.setDataValue("cell_to_update","a new value");
event.api.refreshCells({force:true});
}
}
```